# standalone varwidth option breaks subcaption

Tags: subcaption, standalone, varwidth

I'm trying to generate a figure that is 19.05cm wide (according to submission specifications). I'm defining the width of the `standalone` document using the `varwidth`. I'm also using the `subcaption` package. When I include the `varwidth` option, subcaptions of the figures are not centered and they lose some of the format (for instance, (a) becomes a:).

Any ideas on how to solve this problem? I haven't figured out another way to generate a standalone document that is 19.05cm wide and contains my figures in the right size.

```
\documentclass[preview, varwidth=19.05cm]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Matplotlib2TikZ
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}
        \centering
        \input{Fig2a.tex}\label{Fig2a}
        \caption{Task A: Ground truth}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}
        \centering
        \input{Fig2b.tex}
        \caption{Task B: Ground truth}
        \label{Fig2b}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}    
        \input{Fig2c.tex}
        \vspace{-0.5em}
        \caption{Task A: Real-time annotations}
        \label{Fig2c}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}
        \input{Fig2d.tex}
        \vspace{-0.5em}
        \caption{Task B: Real-time annotations}
        \label{Fig2d}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I am including the output image. I'm generating all the figures using PGF plots, and the sizes are:

```
height=\textwidth,
width=0.45\textwidth,
```

Finally, I have included the `\fbox`s in order to debug (make sure that my `subfigures` contain the figures I'm calling, according to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128225/subcaption-subfigure-not-centered-and-caption-too-narrow)).

[image: output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). To make your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) it would be useful to look at the part about Images, since we don't have the inputed tex-files and it's just about the inserted imagesize.

Comment: Well the `varwidth` option adds a `varwidth` environment (from the , you guessed it, `varwidth` package) which is actually a `minipage` with a variable width. The length given by `varwidth=...` is the *maximum* width.

Comment: Also note, that floating environments like `figure` or `table` are not really targeted by `standalone`. It is rather meant for the diagramms which are inside such environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a way after posting the question. Instead of using `varwidth`, I do not use the option and instead create a `minipage` with the necessary width:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Matplotlib2TikZ
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{19.05cm}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}
    \centering
    \input{Fig2a.tex}\label{Fig2a}
    \caption{Task A: Ground truth}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}
    \centering
    \input{Fig2b.tex}
    \caption{Task B: Ground truth}
    \label{Fig2b}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}    
    \input{Fig2c.tex}
    \vspace{-0.5em}
    \caption{Task A: Real-time annotations}
    \label{Fig2c}
\end{subfigure}
~
\begin{subfigure}[t]{8.8cm}
    \input{Fig2d.tex}
    \vspace{-0.5em}
    \caption{Task B: Real-time annotations}
 \label{Fig2d}
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This generates an image with correct subcaptions: [image: correct subcaptions]